# Javascript cloneNode issue in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, clonenode

The JavaScript below works great in Internet Explorer, but doesnt work in FireFox.

It gets hung up at "NewField is undefined" which would be the line:

```
for (var i=0;i<NewField.length;i++)
```

That is the loop that will rename the form fields on that table row.

Here is where you can see the entire page http://www.sorenwinslow.com/CloneRowTest.asp

```
function CloneRows(TableRowId)
{
var NumRows = document.forms["TestForm"].NumRows.value;
NumRows++;
document.forms["TestForm"].NumRows.value = NumRows;
var RowToClone = document.getElementById(TableRowId);
var NewTableRow = RowToClone.cloneNode(true);
NewTableRow.id = TableRowId + NumRows ;
NewTableRow.style.display = "table-row";
var NewField = NewTableRow.all;
for (var i=0;i<NewField.length;i++)
{
    var theName = NewField[i].name;
    if (theName)
    {
        NewField[i].name = theName + NumRows;
    }
}
var insertHere = document.getElementById(TableRowId);
insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(NewTableRow,insertHere);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.all` does generally not exist, only `document.all`, but it isn't even standard. Internet Explorer has some custom properties but you should not rely on them. You probably want `.children`:

```
var NewField = NewTableRow.children;
```

or `.cells`:

```
var NewField = NewTableRow.cells;
```

Comment: +1 Although (assuming this is an actual table) I'd suggest `NewTableRow.cells` instead of `.children` since FF doesn't support `.children` until `FF 3.5`.

Comment: To replicate `ElementNode.children`, you can just loop through the `childNodes` and filter out any node that isn't `nodeType == 1`. In this case, Pat's dead on. The DOM Table API is massive and certainly useful.

Comment: 'NewTableRow.cells' works. However, how do I access the '<input>' elements inside each cell? '.all' (in I.E) accesses all the elements on that table row and I rename them according to the row count.

Comment: @Soren: If they are in turn children of the children, you can probably iterate over `NewField` and during each iteration, iterate over `NewField[i].children` (or `childNodes`).

Comment: @pimvdb: I am not sure if they are or not. Check out my original page http://www.sorenwinslow.com/CloneRowTest.asp

Comment: **Thank you everyone for your help! It is very much appreciated!** Here is what I ended up with and couldn't have done it without your help: http://www.sorenwinslow.com/CloneRowTest.asp (I would post my code here, but it's too long)